# Remote debugging of multi threaded Python Applications

Tags: python, remote-debugging

How can I do remote debugging of a multi threaded Python application, running on an Embedded Linux based system, from Windows XP or Vista?

So far I have only come across [PyScripter based remote debugging](http://pyscripter.googlepages.com/). How does it perform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used it except a few quick trial runs, but [winpdb](http://winpdb.org/) sounds like it does just what you want:

> Winpdb is a platform independent GPL
>   Python debugger with support for
>   multiple threads, namespace
>   modification, embedded debugging,
>   encrypted communication and is up to
>   20 times faster than pdb.

Comment: WinPDB is excellent. Never used it remotely, but it handles threaded gtk applications perfectly.

Comment: Pydev also supports remote debugging. Please visit http://pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html.

Comment: winpdb is unable to handle python3, or is it?